# emacs-X11 crashes with arithmetic error on launch

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I'm running emacs 23.2.1 on Cygwin on Windows 7.  Yesterday, emacs-X11 was working fine; now it refuses to launch, instead exiting instantly with the error message "Arithmetic error".  Running `emacs-X11 -Q` gives the same error.  The exit status according to bash is 255, but it's 65280 (0xff00) according to Process Monitor.

I can run `emacs-X11 --version` and `emacs-X11 --help` just fine, but any attempt to open a window fails.  I can also run emacs in batch mode (e.g. `emacs-X11 -batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el`).

Running the non-X11 version of emacs (`emacs-nox`, or equivalently `DISPLAY= emacs`; with `DISPLAY` set `:0.0` as I have by default, `emacs` is equivalent to `emacs-X11`) also runs fine.

I can also run other X11 programs (e.g. `xlogo`) just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this or how I can fix it?

Comment: I've had this problem intermittently as well on my work machine.  Rebooting usually resolved it temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'd comment, but I don't have the reputation. :-( ]

I too have seen this problem running cygwin with emacs32 under X.  When I start getting this, other GTK based programs running Cygwin-X also stop working (e.g. navit using gtk). The quick way I have found to resolve it is to restart the X server.   [Rebooting is not needed.]

-John

Comment: Hmm well I eventually had to reboot for an unrelated reason, and that seemed to fix the problem; I forgot to try just restarting X11 before rebooting.